# How to make a resizable html/css layout (duplicate for sure)?

Tags: html, css, resize

I have a problem to make my site resizable
I  searched the net for an easy solution, but in the end I found no one.

The only answer that came close to my goal was this:

```
<div id="topnav">
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="content">
```

Which has 2 divs inside

http://plnkr.co/edit/Zi2f0EPxmtEUmdoFR63B?p=preview

It has 4 parts

[image]

These parts are resizable, like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|                    this is fixed                     |
 -------------------------------------------------------
|            |                                         |
|            |                                         |
|            |                                         |
|            |                                         |
|            |                                         |
|       left<|>right----------up/down    --------------|
|            |                                         |
|            |                                         |
|            |                                         |
|            |                                         |
|            |                                         |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried to implement that, and it worked as promised, but I have problems to implement my layout (in fact layouts, I need to make 2 of them)

The first

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|                    this is fixed                     |
 -------------------------------------------------------
|     25%w   |              50%w            |    25% w |
|     75%h   |              75%h            |          | 33%h
|       left<|>right                        |          |
|            |                              |-up/down--|
|            |                              |          |
|            |                              |          | 33%h
|            |                              |          |
|            |                              |-up/down--|
|------------------up/down-------------left<|>right    |
|                                           |          | 33%h
|                 75%w   25%h               |          |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

The second

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|                    this is fixed                     |
 -------------------------------------------------------
|     25%w   |              50%w            |    25% w |
|     50%h   |              50%h            |          | 50%h
|       left<|>right                   left<|>right    |
|            |                              |          |
|            |                              |          |
|------------------up/down-----------------------------| 
|            |                                         |
|            |                                         | 25%h
|       left<|>right-----------up/down-----------------| 
|            |                                         | 25%h
|            |                  75%w                   |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried the 1st one to make, and half of that I was able to make, but In the end, I had huge problems to implement the others...

I had problems with vertical bar

I hope you can help me solve this, at least some examples how to make 3 div work together side by side, that was my biggest problem.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the three `divs` working correctly. I am in the process of getting the right `divs` on figure 1 to work correctly, its just taking a while (you really lobbed a grenade at us :) ).

Here is the working [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2VE2CeuooNA3BjsSu6NS?p=preview).

You want to work with the percentages to get the `divs` to line up.

Edit: I fixed up a few of the bugs. I did not mess with setting maxes or adjustments for the right `divs`. I think you should be able to manage with those and can base them off of the limits placed on the bottom `div`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['mc.resizer']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.content = 'Hello World';
});
angular.module('mc.resizer', []).directive('resizer', function($document) {

  return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

    $element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
    });

    function mousemove(event) {

      if ($attrs.resizer == 'vertical') {
        // Handle vertical resizer
        var x = event.pageX;

        if ($attrs.resizerMax && x > $attrs.resizerMax) {
          x = parseInt($attrs.resizerMax);
        }

        $element.css({
          left: x + 'px'
        });

        $($attrs.resizerLeft).css({
          width: x + 'px'
        });
        $($attrs.resizerRight).css({
          left: (x + parseInt($attrs.resizerWidth)) + 'px'
        });

        if ($attrs.id == "right-vertical-resizer") {
          $("#sidebar-resizer").css({
            left: '25%'
          });
          $("#top-content").css({
            left: '25%'
          });
          $("#sidebar").css({
            width: '25%'
          });
        }
      } else {
        // Handle horizontal resizer
        var y = window.innerHeight - event.pageY;

        if ($attrs.resizerMax && y > $attrs.resizerMax) {
          y = parseInt($attrs.resizerMax);
        }
        if ($attrs.id == "right-horizontal-1-resizer" || $attrs.id == "right-horizontal-2-resizer") {
          $element.css({
            bottom: (y - 4) + 'px'
          });
          $($attrs.resizerBottom).css({
            top: (event.pageY - 32) + 'px'
          });
        } else if ((event.pageY + 745) > parseInt($attrs.resizerMax)) {
          $element.css({
            bottom: (y - 5) + 'px'
          });
          $($attrs.resizerBottom).css({
            top: (event.pageY - 32) + 'px'
          });
        }

        if ($attrs.id == "content-resizer") {
          $('#sidebar-resizer').css({
            bottom: (y + parseInt($attrs.resizerHeight)) + 'px',
            height: window.innerHeight - y - 35 + 'px'
          })
        }
      }
    }

    function mouseup() {
      $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
    }
  };
});
```

```css
#topnav {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #EEE;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#top-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow: auto;
}

#right-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #EEE;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#right-middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #888;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#right-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 67%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bottom-content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 74%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #777;
}

#sidebar-resizer {
  background-color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 26%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 6px;
  cursor: e-resize;
}

#right-horizontal-1-resizer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 66%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  cursor: n-resize;
}

#right-horizontal-2-resizer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 33%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  cursor: n-resize;
}

#right-vertical-resizer {
  background-color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 25%;
  width: 6px;
  cursor: e-resize;
}

#content-resizer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 26%;
  left: 0;
  right: 25%;
  background-color: #666;
  cursor: n-resize;
}

#left-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#right-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 75%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar-resizer:hover,
#content-resizer:hover,
#right-vertical-resizer:hover,
#right-horizontal-1-resizer:hover,
#right-horizontal-2-resizer:hover {
  background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <html ng-app="myApp">
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" data-semver="2.0.3" data-require="jquery"></script>
  <script data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div id="topnav">Top navbar</div>

  <div id="left-content">

    <div id="sidebar">
      <h3>Side navbar</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="top-content">Top content
      <p>{{content}}</p>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom-content">Bottom content</div>

    <div id="sidebar-resizer" resizer="vertical" resizer-width="6" resizer-left="#sidebar" resizer-right="#top-content" resizer-max="400">
    </div>

    <div id="content-resizer" resizer="horizontal" resizer-height="6" resizer-top="#top-content" resizer-bottom="#bottom-content" resizer-max="800">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right-content">

    <div id="right-top">Right Top content</div>

    <div id="right-middle">Right Middle content</div>

    <div id="right-bottom">Right Bottom content</div>

    <div id="right-horizontal-1-resizer" resizer="horizontal" resizer-height="6" resizer-top="#right-top" resizer-bottom="#right-middle">
    </div>

    <div id="right-horizontal-2-resizer" resizer="horizontal" resizer-height="6" resizer-top="#right-middle" resizer-bottom="#right-bottom">
    </div>
  </div>




  <div id="right-vertical-resizer" resizer="vertical" resizer-width="6" resizer-left="#left-content" resizer-right="#right-content">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But It looks like I ll need more help xD

Comment: can u pls help me make the other one as well?

Comment: I found a problem, to remove the white gap bellow the bottom side, i removed the " height: 100%;" from the #right-content{ in the css file, but then appeared a problem on both right horizontal resizers....try it out...

Comment: @newbie, I fixed the right content issue. Unfortunately, I'm swamped with work and can't help you with your second page. But I think based on the first one, you should manage. First look at the page. How the divs are are split. Create your parent divs first, then the others. It will all fall into place for you. Best of luck.

Comment: @newbie Positioning of the right divs and right horizontal resizers is tweaked here: `if ($attrs.id == "right-horizontal-1-resizer" || $attrs.id ==  "right-horizontal-2-resizer"){
    $element.css({
     bottom: (y - 4)  + 'px'
    });
    $($attrs.resizerBottom).css({
     top: (event.pageY - 32) + 'px'
    });
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3 divs side by side, you should try out flexbox. It's a simple bit of css that helps your position 3 divs next to eachother for instance

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Check it out!

It takes about 5 minutes to find out how it works and it's really easy

Good luck and happy coding!

EDIT: if you want responsive scaling use bootstrap. If this is not the answer to any of your question(s). Then I am terribly sorry

Comment: I have no problem placing the 3 div side by side, I just cannot make the line between them act as it should be, when i move the line between the 1st and the 2nd, just thte 2 of them have to be resized, the 3rd one on the left side should not be changed.....as well as when I use the line between the 2nd and the 3rd, the 1st one should not be changed....I hope you understand what i mean...Thx anyway

Comment: Yeah I didnt understand your question well enough, my bad on that part. I'll try to remake the situation at hand when I have time. I won't give up on helping you with this

Comment: I looked at the snipper on plunker, you have a duplicate background color set on your #topnav (x

Comment: one step at a time c;

Answer (score 0):

Percentage width and height combined with inline-block attribute, will give you a starting point of want you want to achieve like the example below

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}
.container{
  height:100%;
  line-height:0;
 
}
.section{
  display:inline-block;
}
.w75{
  width:75%;
}
.w33{
  width:33.333%;
}
.w66{
  width:66.666%;
}
.w25{
  width:25%;
}
.w100{
  width:100%;  
}
.h100{
  height:100%;
}
.h75{
  height: 75%;
}
.h33{
  height:33.333%;
}
.h25{
  height:25%;
}
.red{
  background:red;
}
.blue{
  background:blue;
}
.green{
  background:green;
}
.brown{
 background:brown;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <section class="section w75 h100">
      <section class="section w33 h75 red">

      </section><section class="section w66 h75 blue">
     
      </section><section class="section w100 h25 green">
  
      </section>
    </section><section class="section w25 h100">
      <section class="section w100 h33 green">
       
      </section><section class="section w100 h33 red">
    
      </section><section class="section w100 h33 brown">

      </section>
    </section>
  <div>
```

be carefull to avoid the space between inline-block elements refer [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: thx man, but thats not what I asked, I just have problems with the resize lines....